# Показ TextView не в том месте

Tags: android

Добрый вечер! 
Давно искал таймер обратного отсчета и, блуждая по сайту, нашел:

[image: На телефоне]
[image: В Android Studio]

Мне нужен был показ только дней, так что я немного подкорректировал код.
Вопрос состоит в том, что я никак не могу переместить на экране этот TextView с содержимым отсчета дней до события.
Иными словами, он находится наверху экрана, а мне необходимо, чтобы он был внизу.

Двигая TextView (id: tv2) по экрану, сдвиг в эмуляторе не происходит, все данные все равно отображаются в верхнем левом углу экрана.
В чем может быть проблема? Как ее можно решить?

**Разметка**:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  tools:context=".ImagePickerActivity" >

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**код**:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
TextView tv2;
long diff;
long milliseconds;
long endTime;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv2 = new TextView(this);
    this.setContentView(tv2);
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm");
    formatter.setLenient(false);

    String oldTime = "01.08.2015, 12:00";
    Date oldDate;
    try {
        oldDate = formatter.parse(oldTime);
        milliseconds = oldDate.getTime();

        //long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // do your work...
        long endTime=System.currentTimeMillis();

        diff = endTime-milliseconds;

        Log.e("day", "miliday"+diff);
        long seconds = (long) (diff / 1000) % 60 ;
        Log.e("secnd", "miliday"+seconds);
        long minutes = (long) ((diff / (1000*60)) % 60);
        Log.e("minute", "miliday"+minutes);
        long hours   = (long) ((diff / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
        Log.e("hour", "miliday"+hours);
        long days = (int)((diff / (1000*60*60*24)) % 365);
        Log.e("days", "miliday"+days);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    Long serverUptimeSeconds = (System.currentTimeMillis() - milliseconds) / 1000;


    String serverUptimeText = String.format("%d days %d hours %d minutes %d seconds",
            serverUptimeSeconds / 86400,
            ( serverUptimeSeconds % 86400) / 3600 ,
            ((serverUptimeSeconds % 86400) % 3600 ) / 60,
            ((serverUptimeSeconds % 86400) % 3600 ) % 60
    );


    Log.v("jjj", "miliday"+serverUptimeText);
    MyCount counter = new MyCount(milliseconds,1000);
    counter.start();


}


// countdowntimer is an abstract class, so extend it and fill in methods
public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {
    public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        tv2.setText("done!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        //tv.setText("Left: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

        long diff = endTime - millisUntilFinished;
        Log.e("left", "miliday"+diff);
        long seconds = (long) (diff / 1000) % 60 ;
        //Log.e("secnd", "miliday"+seconds);
        long minutes = (long) ((diff / (1000*60)) % 60);
        //Log.e("minute", "miliday"+minutes);
        long hours   = (long) ((diff / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
        //Log.e("hour", "miliday"+hours);
        int days = (int)((diff / (1000*60*60*24)) % 365);
        Log.v("days", "miliday"+days);


        Long serverUptimeSeconds =
                (millisUntilFinished - System.currentTimeMillis()) / 2000;


        String serverUptimeText =
                String.format("%d",
                        serverUptimeSeconds / 86400,
                        ( serverUptimeSeconds % 86400) / 3600 ,
                        ((serverUptimeSeconds % 86400) % 3600 ) / 60,
                        ((serverUptimeSeconds % 86400) % 3600 ) % 60
                );

        Log.v("new its", "miliday"+serverUptimeText);

        // tv.setText(days +":"+hours+":"+minutes + ":" + seconds);

        tv2.setText(serverUptimeText);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Расположение виджетов задается в разметке, а не в коде. Где она?

Comment: в приведенном коде вы ничего никуда не двигаете

Comment: Как я понимаю, содержимое отсчета времени должно показываться на  TextView2, верно? Почему же тогда оно появляется только в верхнем левом углу?

Comment: Как вы пробовали перемещать этот `TextView` ? Для размещения снизу используйте атрибут `android:layout_gravity = "bottom"` для виджета

Comment: @pavlofff, так и разместил: добавил в Gravity атрибут "bottom". дело в том, что при запуске на эмуляторе вообще не показывается ничего (никакие элементы, кроме дней до события). А в android studio я добавил TextView. Сейчас прикреплю 2 скриншота.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в методе `onCreate` вызывается

```
tv2 = new TextView(this);
this.setContentView(tv2);
```

а надо

```
tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
```

Метод `setContentView()` в нормальной ситуации должен вызываться 1 раз в методе `onCreate()`, т.к. он предназначен для установки контента(слой с вашими элементами `view`) который будет отображен на экране, и желательно сразу после `super.onCreate()`, чтобы не ловить потом NPE при поиске вьюх и установки для них значений.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое! Очень помогли!